# How to use jsp variable in detached JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

For Example: 
`String str = "A";`

I use java variable in javascript. and it shows "A" in html.

and After separating the .js file it shows `<%=str%>` in html.

Can not use .js file separation?

Comment: your question is not clear . but as i understand you have to use Double quote then variable name  : "<%=str%>"  instead of <%=str%>

Comment: Your JavaScript files are not processed by the JSP compiler. You can configure the JSP compiler to do so though.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just put your JavaScript in a JSP file with the following header: `<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" %>` and then just include it as normal `<script src="whatever.jsp"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your requirements correctly

copying from the comment  by @Robby Cornelissen

> Your JavaScript files are not processed by the JSP compiler. You can
>   configure the JSP compiler to do so though.....

You can add script tag in your jsp page as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = <%=str%>
</script>
```

and replace the `<%=str%>` in the seprated `.js` script file

with `str`

Alternatively,

You could just put your JavaScript in a JSP file with the following header:

`<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" %>`

and then just include it as normal

```
<script src="whatever.jsp"></script>
```

@Thanks to @Robby Cornelissen for remanding me about alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a JSP variable in a non-JSP page.

Your .js file is not processed by the server. Hence the javascript variable is not initialised to your JSP data.

You can rename your javascript file to `something.jsp`. and write the javascript code in `something.jsp` file under script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't use jsp variables in javascript
Long answer: you can :)

The thing is, jasper (jsp parser) process your jsp files before serving them to the browser, but do not parse js files. 
What I usually do is add a short javascript section in jsp file where I assign all java variables(the model variables) to javascript object that will be accessible to your js functions. Just make sure that your script section is loaded first and than your js files.